# How an object can be treated as an array and iterates through it and save the response in javascript with trie data structure?

Tags: javascript, node.js, trie, family-tree

I am a beginner in the data structure. I have just started learning it. I am trying to create a family structure using the trie data structure. I am referring to the document for that on github here:
https://gist.github.com/tpae/72e1c54471e88b689f85ad2b3940a8f0#file-trie-js-L44

This is some code.

```
function TrieNode(key) {
  // the "key" value will be the character in sequence
  this.key = key;
  
  // we keep a reference to parent
  this.parent = null;
  
  // we have hash of children
  this.children = {};
  
  // check to see if the node is at the end
  this.end = false;
}

// -----------------------------------------

// we implement Trie with just a simple root with null value.
function Trie() {
  this.root = new TrieNode(null);
}

// inserts a word into the trie.
// time complexity: O(k), k = word length
Trie.prototype.insert = function(word) {
  var node = this.root; // we start at the root 
  
  // for every character in the word
  for(var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    // check to see if character node exists in children.
    if (!node.children[word[i]]) {
      // if it doesn't exist, we then create it.
      node.children[word[i]] = new TrieNode(word[i]);
      
      // we also assign the parent to the child node.
      node.children[word[i]].parent = node;
    }
    
    // proceed to the next depth in the trie.
    node = node.children[word[i]];
    
    // finally, we check to see if it's the last word.
    if (i == word.length-1) {
      // if it is, we set the end flag to true.
      node.end = true;
    }
  }
};
```

My doubt is while inserting the node, how we are iterating through word and creating a node as:

```
 node.children[word[i]]
```

which is not understandable to me. Also how key, parent, children are declared in function TrieNode? Are they treated as global variables which are initialized whenever an object is created? And why root has been declared in other functions and how does it work?
P.S. I have to insert the tree like this:

```
var familyHead = {
      name: 'Chit',
      gender:'Male',
      grandfather:'',
      grandmother:'',
      father:'Shan',
      mother:'Anga',
      wife:'Amba',
    children : [
    {
      name: 'Chit',
      gender:'Male',
      grandfather:'',
      grandmother:'',
      father:'Shan',
      mother:'Anga',
      wife:'Amba',
      children :[]
}]
```

} ... continue

Comment: What don't you understand about `node.children[word[i]]`? if `word` is a string like `HELLO`, then `word[i]` is a letter in that string like `H`.  `children` is a JavaScript object, so we're talking about a property of that object with the key `H`, which will be a `TrieNode`.  And do you understand what `this.children = {}` does?  Are you following that much?  Can you be really specific about what you do or do not understand here?

Comment: Thanks, @Wyck for your inputs here. Ya now I get that. My other doubt is that we are directly inserting words like 'hello', 'apple' etc., or any strings by calling the insert function. I want to understand what is happening inside the insert method? means what do children object storing and parent? Also, can you see my family tree structure. How to insert a tree like that and then fetch the relationship based on input as a name?

Comment: Beware: [the difference between ___tree___ and ___trie___](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4737904/difference-between-tries-and-trees)  You likely just need a **tree** to store a _family tree_.  A **trie** is for efficiently storing a collection of words by reusing representations of the common prefix substrings of those words.  For example, the words `grandfather` and `grandmother` in a trie will store the common letters `g`,`r`,`a`,`n`,`d` only once.  With the representations of the words `father` and `mother` stored beneath the representation of the word `grand` in the trie.

Comment: gotcha!! Can you tell me about the function TrieNode(key) {}? In this how parent, children objects are declared directly? Are they global variables? Why first it is not declared using 'var' or 'let' keyword and then use it? @Wyck

Comment: They are not global variables.  They are properties of the object.  I wrote a full answer.  Forgive my verbosity if your problem is just that you don't understand how constructors, properties and variables work.  If that's the case, then ask a more target question about the specific aspect of the language that gives you trouble with greatly reduced scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give JavaScript objects properties that refer to the related objects accomplish what you want to form a ***graph***.  (Do not use a ***trie***, that's for something else.).

For example, create a plain JavaScript object for each person.

```
// Create an to represent each unique person
const chit = { name: 'Chit', gender: 'male' };
const shan = { name: 'Shan', gender: 'male' };
const anga = { name: 'Anga', gender: 'female' };
const anba = { name: 'Anba', gender: 'female' };

// Give them properties that establish the relationships as required
chit.father = shan;
chit.mother = anga;
chit.wife = amba;
/// ...
```

These are uni-directional links so far. If you also want the father to have an array of their children, then you'll have to *maintain* this data structure as you build it.  You'll want to have some convenience functions for doing this.

To establish a parent-child relationship between two people minimally one thing must happen:

1. The child object should have its `parent` property set to the parent object.

If, as a matter of convenience or efficiency, you also want to maintain a cache of the list of children each person has then furthermore:

2. The parent object should have the child object added to its `children` array.

Doing so ***overspecifies*** the parent-child relationship and so the data structure must maintain integrity. This means that you'll want to provide functions to make modifications to the tree while checking for inconsistencies.  For example, it may not make sense to simultaneously try to establish two parent-child relationships for the same child, or to have a child with no parent (*someone* will need to have no parent because you can't store an infinitely deep generational history), or to have a person listed as a child but not also simultaneously have that same child listed as having the same parent.

In such a function, one might now go so far as to check the whole tree for integrity, but it may be sufficient to just check the parts of the structure being modified.

When establishing a new parent-child relationship, check to see if the child already has a parent.  There are two strategies for dealing with this if they do, depending on whether it makes sense to edit the otherwise biologically immutable property of who is one's parent (for example, consider a process like *adoption*)

1. Throw an exception.
2. Edit the relationship by *removing* the child from the parent's array of children before updating to set the new parent.

Here I will provide an implementation that permits one parent of each gender.  I'll map the gender of the parent to either `mother` or `father` property names just to illustrate the convenience of doing so.  If you find you need to represent families with two mothers, for example, then you will need to make use an array of parents instead.  (But your example uses `mother` and `father`, and so shall I.)

```
const parent_property_name = {
  male: 'father',
  female: 'mother'
};

function establishParentChildRelationship(parent, child) {
   if (!child.parent) child.parent = {};
   if (child[parent_property_name[parent.gender]]) throw new Error('child already has a parent of that gender');
   child[parent_property_name[parent.gender]] = parent;
   if (!parent.children) parent.children = [];
   parent.children.push(child);
}
```

Hopefully you can see that because of the upkeep required that it is not typically done to further store explicit **grandfather** and **grandmother** relationships in the tree.  The father of a father is implicitly the grandfather and can be determined as such.  Similarly the siblings of a parent are aunts and uncles, etc.  Cousins and second cousins can all be determined based on just the parent-child relationships.  There's no need to explicitly store it again.  Furthermore one must consider whether or not you need to explicitly define **mother** and **father** because they may come from `parent` + `gender`. (or is it fine not to represent concepts like female-father?  The details of these things will likely be defined by the legal framework in which you are working. But the world is a complex place.)

The marital relationships (legal or religious or otherwise), however, do require additional links.  One must also consider whether the data structure is to permit plural marriage (which may require an array, much like children) and same-gender marriage ('married' + 'gender' => 'husband' or 'wife').  But for monogamous marriages, one could imagine, minimally, just representing this with `maritalPartner`.

```
function establishMonogamousMaritalPartnerRelationship(person1, person2) {
   if (person1.maritalPartner || person2.maritalPartner) throw new Error('already married!');
   person1.maritalPartner = person2;
   person2.maritalPartner = person1;
```

You could also use the trick of mapping gender to `husband` or `wife` as necessary.  Or if you want to represent plural marriage, then you could use an array of partners (much like was done with children.)

The data structure may need to be modified again to be able to represent the complexities of these relationships changing over time.  (For example divorce or 2nd marriage, adoption, emancipation, gender transition or reassignment, etc.)

---

Let me also take a moment to clarify what the ***trie*** is for.  (It is **not** applicable to the family tree.)

The trie represents words as a tree, where each node is a letter and each node's parent node is the letter that came before it.  A complete word is marked with a flag on the node in the tree that is that words final letter.

Consider a trie storing the words `be`, `bee`, `bell`, and `ball`:

```
.
└── b
    ├── a
    │   └── l
    │       └── l*
    └── e*
        ├── e*
        └── l
            └── l*
```

Nodes marked with a `*` represent complete words (with the `end` flag in your example).  Note that a word may end even if more letters are permitted to follow it to form a different work.  (e.g.:  `be` is a word, even though it may be followed by `e` or `l`).  Every node with an `end` flag, represents a word determined by its ancestry in the tree.

---

Finally, let me quickly address your question about the nature of how `key`, `parent`, and `children` are declared in function `TrieNode`.

What you are looking at is a JavaScript ***constructor***.  I suggest you read [the basics](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_constructors.asp)  Or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114024/constructors-in-javascript-objects).

But in this specific case, calling `new TrieNode('X')` will create a JavaScript object that looks basically like this:

```
{ key: 'X', parent: null, children: {}, end: false }
```

Comment: I dont understand these 2 statements:     node.children[word[i]] = new TrieNode(word[i]);
      
      // we also assign the parent to the child node.
      node.children[word[i]].parent = node;

Here how index of children could be other than integer? how node.children[c] justifies? if the word inserted suppose is = 'chit' ?

Comment: Sounds like you need to brush up on the basics of JavaScript.  In JavaScript an object is a collection of key-value pairs where the key is a string (or some special thing called a Symbol).  The "index" in this case is a string.  e.g.:  `let obj = { "H" : "Hello", "W": "World" }` gives `obj["H"] === "Hello"` and `obj["W"] === "World"`, also `obj.H === "Hello"` and `obj.W === "World"`.  `H` and `W` are the property keys (strings) and `Hello` and `World` are the property values (also strings in this case).   for strings `word[3]` is the 4th letter of the string in word. e.g.: `"chit"[3] === "t"`

Comment: `node.children[word[i]]` accesses the `i`th letter of `word` (let's say its the `t` in `chit`) and accesses a property called `t` in the object stored in `node.children`, which is like a dictionary mapping letters to objects -- as are the nodes in a trie.  Each node has such a dictionary (and each letter may have another such node beneath it, thus forming a tree).